# Using the Object.inspect / Object.to_s on a class derived from Hash

Tags: ruby

I have a class derived from Hash. When I use it in IRB, it dumps the contents of the hash to the console. Instead, I would like it to print the same way as the `Object.inspect/.to_s` (not sure which) in the form `#<MyHash:0x201e4c0>`. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT** I had to remove the secondary question because it led to confusion. The question above is what I need answered. This is what I removed:

*Is there a way to call the method of a class higher up in the inheritance hierarchy by any chance?*

Answer (score 3):

One of the basic chores when writing a new class that you want to share to others is to define a few basic methods, among them `#inspect`, `#to_s`, `#==`, `#<=>` and several others. So you yourself have to write your `inspect` function when making a new class.

So much for your duties. But now, to your question, which can be generally stated as how to utilize methods of deep ancestors in a class, one way would be like this:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def inspect
    Object.instance_method( :inspect ).bind( self ).call
  end
end
```

Here, the requirement is that `MyHash` be a descendant of `Object`, otherwise the UnboundMethod instance won't bind to it. (For `Object`, this is obviously true, but might not be the case in general.)

UPDATED AFTER COMMENTS:

The code above allows MyHash to call Object instance method `inspect`. To percieve the effect strongly, one has to repeat the procedure with method `to_s`, which is called by Object#inspect:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def inspect
    Object.instance_method( :inspect ).bind( self ).call
  end
end

h = MyHash[ a: 1, b: 2 ]
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2 }
# The above code did work, but Object#inspect happens to call to_s() instance method
# To see the change

class MyHash
  def to_s
    Object.instance_method( :to_s ).bind( self ).call
  end
end

h.inspect
#=> "#<MyHash:0x90ee01c>"
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet in IRB and it still dumps the contents of the hash to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, can you define a class in Ruby that is not a descendant of Object?

Comment: True, you have two question mark ended sentences in your OP, first one being "How do I achieve this?", and second "Is there a way ... ?". My code snippet is a (one possible) answer to the second. To answer yourself the first, do the same for :to_s method, on which Object#inspect relies.

Comment: Agreed, my second question was asking whether this is possibly a way to resolve the issue, but when I use your line in the .to_s method, it gives an error, and when I use it as-is, it changes nothing. I will modify my question to remove the second question, as I guess this is confusing. My primary problem still stands.

Comment: OK, I read your comment too fast and I have not noticed the question edit, when I already edited my answer :) The code I give works in my irb.