# Can a ruby object call super on a "grandparent"?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

If I have a class `Salad` with a method `chew` and I use `super` in it, it will call the next available `chew` method available going up the chain of ancestors.  What if I want to "reach two levels up" (to the second available `chew` method going up the chain)?  Is there any way to do that without adding `super` to the first ancestor's method?

To make this a little more concrete, suppose this is my `Salad` class, with a `salad` object:

```
class Salad < Food
  include Almonds
  include Gorgonzola
  include Spinach
  include Dressing

  def chew
    super
  end
end

salad = Salad.new
```

The array of the ancestors would be like this:

```
[Salad, Dressing, Spinach, Gorgonzola, Almonds, Food, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

If I want `salad.chew` to trigger the `chew` method in `Spinach` without adding `super` to Dressing#chew, is that possible?   Is there a way to reach two levels up (in the same way that  `super` "reaches" one level up)?

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example that illustrates *why* you're trying to do what you're trying to do?

Comment: For example, to resolve linearization of inheritance diamonds the way programmer wants, if I may answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do what you are describing, and that way is through methods `#method` and `#instance_method`, as in `method = Spinach.instance_method( :chew )`, which you can then bind to Salad, or to metaclasses of Salad instances, as in `method.bind( Salad )`. This mechanism is not as neat as using the convenience keyword `super`, but offers a superset of `super`'s functionality. There are a few more details, but trust me, this way, you can do anything you want. That's the power of Ruby – you can do anything, up to the point that for the Lispiest magic, you need `Ripper`, and (the thus far unfinished) [`Sorcerer`](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer).

(For a usage example, see my other answer at [Using the Object.inspect / Object.to_s on a class derived from Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472195))

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do what you are describing (and for good reason). Any use of the "super-super" keyword which you describe would be too tightly coupled to the details of your inheritance chain (and which classes/modules in that chain implement a given method). It would be very brittle; if such a keyword existed, and you used it, then small changes like moving a method definition would very easily break things. It would also be very confusing for readers of your code.

The purpose of the `super` keyword is: you can take a class, subclass it, override a method, and add some new behaviors to that method, while still doing everything that the method originally did. `super` effectively says: "now perform the **default** behavior for this method". That works regardless of whether that "default" behavior is defined in the superclass, super-superclass, a module, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how to achieve calling the `chew` method on all the modules, there is a better solution that is using composition. Modules are for behavior and if you think about your Salad class, you don't want it to behave like a Spinach or Almonds, you want it to be composed of them. So when you `chew` a salad you `chew` each of its components.